# Xamarin iOS excessive mobiledevice provisioning files being copied to Mac via Visual Studio

Tags: ios, xamarin, profile, provisioning

Anyone else having this problem?

My configuration as of 5/15/2020...

MacBook Air macOS Catalina 10.15.4
Xcode versions 11.4.1 (11E503a)
PC Windows 10 Pro version 1909 OS build 18363.778
Visual Studio 2019 version 16.5.5
Xamarin.Forms 4.5.0.617
Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs version 3.3.0
iPhone 7 Plus
Model Number MPR02LL/A
Software version 13.4.1

MacBook and PC connected via LAN directly to a GigSwitch. iPhone connected
to same network via WiFi.

What is the issue?

I have noticed Visual Studio 2019 is causing an excessive number of mobile device provisioning files to be created on my Mac. The total number of files seems to be increasing by three a day (121 of them this morning). When I manually purge these file on the Mac and then use Xcode/Preferrences/Accounts/[Download Manual Profiles] I end up with only 6 profile files.

How did I discover this?

I have been encountering "intermittent" iOS (APNs) Azure notification hub registration issues. Sometimes iOS registration and push notifications work, and sometimes they do not (with zero code changes). Android, using the same Azure notification hub definition, works fine all of the time. I have tested with multiple Apple physical devices and have had the same issue.

I have noticed that once I am able to successfully register a physical iOS device with Azure notification hubs I am able to receive push notifications for days. When I remove Azure iOS (APNs) registrations via Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs.NotificationHubClient.DeleteRegistrationAsync sometimes I am able to re-register immediately, and most of the time re-registration will takes hours or days. I am using sample code from Microsoft (NotificationHubSample) with only minor modifications to the Dispatcher of which allows me to view and remove registered devices at Azure. When this issue occurs callbacks FailedToRegisterForRemoteNotifications and/or DidReceiveRemoteNotification are not being called in AppDelegate.cs upon a clean installation of the app. The Azure portal shows registration attempts were made.

I am using the latest of everything (Mac OS, PC Windows + Visual Studio 2019, iPhone OS). This problem is frustrating as over half my development time is waiting for Azure iOS (APNs) registrations to begin magically working ... apparently on its own.

I have read through many troubleshooting links and most of them discuss configuration issues not intermittent ones and seem to be geared toward initial setup related issues. I have found nothing at all anywhere on monitoring APNs (Apple Push Notification services).

When registrations stop working I have had most success (of you want to call it that) cleaning my Visual Studio 2019 Xamarin Forms solution, manually "deleting all mobile provisioning profiles from the Mac", uninstalling the app from the iPhone, shutting down the Mac and the iPhone, shutting down my PC, let everything sit quietly for minutes, hours, and sometimes an entire day, and then boot everything up fresh. Then, sometimes things begin working normally. When I first started doing this I noticed the excessive number of Xcode mobile device provisioning files on the Mac.

Comment: Hi , if using Manual provisioning , does it also show an excessive number of mobile device provisioning files ?

Comment: Yes.  Same issue.  I manually deleted the MobileDevice provisioning profiles from the Mac (134 of them), changed my iOS Project bundle signing to "Manual Provisioning", stopped and restarted Visual Studio 2019.  Once Visual Studio connected the paired Mac, I had 134 provisioning files in the MobileDevice folder on the Mac.

Comment: Okey , that's strange . I am interesting about the 134 provisioning files whether all are generated by the xamarin ios application developed in this PC .

Comment: I have 145 files today.  Not sure what is going on here.

Comment: I have two primary Xamarin forms apps that I am working with.  One from the Xamarin/Microsoft team "NotificationHubSample" (Android and iOS).  The other is a custom Xamarin Forms iOS/Android app that has been in development for a year of which I am adding push notifications.  Both of these Visual Studio 2019 (PC) solutions cause the creation of the MobileDevice profile files on the Mac with an increasing rate of about three a day.  Now the are up to 153.

Comment: I have 162 MobileDevice provisioning files on my Mac today.  What's up Microsoft?

Comment: Could you share a screenshot of the view of keychains which contains an excessive number of mobile device provisioning files ? this will be helpful to check the reason.

Comment: Hi ,  I think this problem should be related to your native environment . If need more help ,you can submit it to [Microsoft Support Topic here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/supportforbusiness/productselection?sapId=211dd84f-3474-c3c5-79bf-66db630c92a6)  Thanks for replying  :-)